# Infinite fadeOut / fadeIn substitution of two list items on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have this almost working but not quite. I just want to be able to keep switching between two unordered list items on a button click fading the first item out as the second fades in. Then do it the opposite way on another click. On the first click it works, as does the second, but I'm not sure where to go after that. The first li item is just a bg image that will change to some text on click, then back to the image on another click. Thanks in advance. T

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').click( function() {
        $('.contentOne').fadeOut( 'slow', function() { 
            $('.contentTwo').fadeIn('slow', function() { 
                $('#myButton').click(function() {
                    $('.contentTwo').fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
                        $('.contentOne').fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `fadeToggle` for both elements on one `click`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

`html`

```
<button id="changeToText">
  Change
</button>

<div class="gizBrainButton">
  first class
</div>
<div class="gizBrainButton">
  first class
</div>
<div class="showGizText" style="display:none;">
  Second class
</div>
<div class="showGizText" style="display:none;">
  Second class
</div>
```

`js`

```
$('#changeToText').click(function() {
  if ($('.gizBrainButton').is(':visible')) {
    $('.gizBrainButton').fadeToggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
      $('.showGizText').fadeToggle(1000);
    });
  } else if($('.showGizText').is(':visible')) {
    $('.showGizText').fadeToggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
      $('.gizBrainButton').fadeToggle(1000);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This one just refreshes my page when I click my button. Nothing changed in the content

Comment: Did you change selectors from my example ?

Comment: Yes. I see you're code has changed a little. I will try that.

Comment: $('#changeToText').click(function() {
  $('.gizBrainButton').fadeToggle(1000).promise().done(function() {
    $('.showGizText').fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});

Comment: I don't know how click could reload your page (if we are talking only about this code). I made example on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/53dwh5wz/2/

Comment: That's working now. I just made the click event a button , rather than an <a>. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could store the state of one of the content parts and toggle visibilty based on that. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /** @var boolean */
    var isContentOneVisible = true;
    /** @var string */
    var fadeSpeed = 'slow';

    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        if (isContentOneVisible) {
            $('.contentOne').fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
            $('.contentTwo').fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
            isContentOneVisible = false;
            return;
        }

        $('.contentOne').fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
        $('.contentTwo').fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
        isContentOneVisible = true;
    });
});
```

jQuery provides `fadeToggle` aswell. It would ease implementing your use case as it keeps track of state itself.

I would prefer a lightweight vanilla solution. For example, you could toggle a classname on an element wrapping the elements you want to show and hide. Use CSS to toggle their visibility, possibly using transitions to mimic the effect jQuery implemented.

Below some example code to get you going.

HTML:

```
<button class='contentToggler'>Show secondary content</button>
<ul class='toggleableContent'>
    <li class='toggleableContent__item toggleableContent__item--first'><!-- content --></li>
    <li class='toggleableContent__item toggleableContent__item--second'><!-- content --></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.toggleableContent__item {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.toggleableContent--isToggled .toggleableContent__item--first,
.toggleableContent__item--second {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggleableContent--isToggled .toggleableContent__item--second {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    var toggler = document.querySelector('.contentToggler');
    var toggleableContent = document.querySelector('.toggleableContent');

    if (!toggler || !toggleableContent) {
        return;
    }

    toggler.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        toggleableContent.classList.toggle('toggleableContent--isToggled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I added a basic example for you to play around with if you want to drop jQuery to solve this for you (it's kind of a sledgehammer). Don't worry if you don't want to, then it's just here to stay for future reference.